# set SESSION variable when clicking an <a href>

Tags: php, session, post, href

I have a php script which prints href links on the page like this:

```
//...
echo"<link><a href=\"nextpage.php\">$table_list[$i]</a><br>";
//...
```

$table_list has table names from my database, and I want to go to **nextpage** with say `$_SESSION['tablename']=$table_list[$i];`

How can I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: What is that `<link>` doing there next to `<a>`? It's not even closed.

Comment: hmm, didn't notice. It works this way but yes it's a mistake. See I'm a copy paster, looks like a bad one, too :)

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I chose Kemal's since it was the earliest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the value you want by appending a query string to the link. Something like:

```
echo "...nextpage.php?tablename=$table_list[$i]...";
```

Then in `nextpage.php`, grab the value of `$_GET['tablename']` and put it in the user's session.

```
$_SESSION['tablename'] = $_GET['tablename'];
```

Comment: Wow, didn't think it was that easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you right, you want to set the `$table_list[$i]` to the the session as `$_SESSION["tablename"]` when nextpage is called.

Just write the link as follows:

```
echo "<a href=\"nextpage.php?table=" . urlencode($table_list[$i]) . "\">" . $table_list[$i] . "</a>";
```

so in `nextpage.php` you have `$_GET["table"]` and then you can do this:

```
$_SESSION["tablename"] = $_GET["table"]
```

i hope i understood your question right.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways to go about doing this.  The easiest way would be to include a piece of code in the header of your nextpage.php which sets the session var.

The code on your current page should change to something like this:

```
echo "<link><a href=\"nextpage.php?tablename=$table_list[i]\">$table_list[$i]</a><br>";
```

Then on nextpage.php you can use a `get` request to pull the value of session_var and set it to your session var.

```
$tablename = $_GET['tablename'];
$_SESSION['tablename'] = $tablename;
```

Now obviously you will have to sanitize the get data before you set the session data.  To not do so would be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the variable via GET:

```
//...
echo"<a href=\"nextpage.php?value=$table_list[$i]\">$table_list[$i]</a><br>";
//...
```

and the retrieve it:

```
$_SESSION['tablename']=$_GET["value"]
```